# Emtpy "page" in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Jo, first of all I'm sorry for that title but I couldn't find a better title.
So my question is how do I code an "empty page" ?
Let me explain:
When I press a button, another "form" should appear. Not a new window.
The other objects should just disappear. Do I code this with the "Visibility" function or is there any other trick to do this?

Greetings from the US

Comment: You don't mean totally empty really, do you?  I guess you mean a single window app which navigates by switching out most if the content?  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just create new Page in your project. Then place Frame control to your Window and in your Button_Click event set the Content property to your empty page.

```
frameControl.Content = new EmptyPage();
```

It may be good idea to initialise the EmptyPage only once and not on every button click.